# Technique to avoid this parse error? JSON +double quote

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

We know in JSON  string object we have property and its value as 
“Property”:”Value”

Suppose my Value contains a double quote, Like “Property”: “my country is “uk” ”

We know that this is going to give parse error on JSON.parse().

What is the technique to avoid this parse error?

Answer (score 8):

You can use `backslash` to escape the double qoute, read more about escape character over [here](http://www.quackit.com/javascript/tutorial/javascript_escape_characters.cfm).

*Change*

```
“my country is “uk” ”
```

*To*

```
“my country is \“uk\” ”
```

Answer (score 3):

If you're encoding an object into JSON, you can use `JSON.stringify()`:

```
JSON.stringify({
    Property: 'my country is "uk"'
})
// {"Property":"my country is \"uk\""}
```

As you can see from above example, the notation `\"` is used to properly escape double quotes.